# NVDA role=alertdialog is not announcing the description

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

NVDA accessibility program does not announce (sound) the dialog alert text (description) when the alert dialog appears automatically after the page is loaded.

It works if you trigger the alert dialog by clicking the button.

However, the speech viewer tool works well for both.

Here is my code

https://codepen.io/merttanriverdi/pen/YzBNmEp

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Using aria-alertdialog to Identify Errors</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            showDialog();

            $('#trigger-alertdialog').click(function () {
                showDialog();
            });
        });

        function showDialog() {
            $('main').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
            var lastFocus = document.activeElement;
            var modalOverlay = $('<div>').attr({id: "modalOverlay", tabindex: "0"});
            $(modalOverlay).appendTo('body');
            var dialog = $('<div>').attr({
                role: "alertdialog",
                "aria-labelledby": "alertHeading",
                "aria-describedby": "alertText",
                tabindex: "0"
            });
            $(dialog).html('<div id="firstElement" tabindex="0"></div><h1 id="alertHeading">Error</h1><div id="alertText">Employee\'s Birth Date is after their hire date. Please verify the birth date and hire date.</div><button id="firstButton">Save and Continue</button><button id="lastButton">Return to page and correct error</button><div id="lastElement" tabindex="0"></div>').appendTo('body');
            $('#firstButton').focus();

            $('#lastElement').focusin(function (e) {
                $('#firstButton').focus();
            });
            $('#firstElement').focusin(function (e) {
                $('#lastButton').focus();
            });

            $('[role=alertdialog] button').click(function (e) {
                $('main').attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
                $(modalOverlay).remove();
                $(dialog).remove();
                lastFocus.focus();
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #modalOverlay {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
            background-color: #000;
            opacity: 0.5;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        [role=alertdialog] {
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            border: thin #000 solid;
            background-color: #fff;
            z-index: 3;
            position: fixed;
            top: 25%;
            left: 25%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <h1>Using aria-alertdialog to Identify Errors</h1>
    <p>This example shows how role=&quot;alertdialog&quot; can be used to notify someone they have entered invalid
        information.</p>
    <button id="trigger-alertdialog">Trigger Alertdialog</button>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

NVDA program should announce the alert text by reading the text "Employee's Birth Date is after their hire date. Please verify the birth date and hire date." , also can be announce the buttons.

Comment: Is it still the same if you add a small delay, instead of showing the dialog directly at page load ? Try with different delays, for example 100ms, 500ms, 1000ms...

Comment: @QuentinC, I tried but it didn't work. If I enter/press any key before the dialogue shows, it works.

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution, anyone can help me?

Comment: IF it works well when you do it at another time, there is probably no 100% reliable solution for your case. But, in fact, do you really need to pop-up an alert dialog directly at page load ? Unless you have a good reason, it isn't very good UX design. Such pop-ups are often annoying, even more for screen reader users. It would be better, and more reliable, if you pop it up only after an user interaction which makes sense.

Comment: I need it to announce something to the user. It should alert dialog directly at page load. BTW thanks for your comment

Comment: I need it to announce something to the user. ==> Of course, but what ? Maybe you can do it in another way. Maybe it's better with a snackbar style, where the user doesn't need to close the dialog after having heard the anouncement, using alert instead of alertdialog.